# Why isn't my function returning the value it should?

Tags: php, function

I have a function.

```
function activeCheck($activeMain) {
    //check if activateBox is being used, if yes change value to '1'

    if ($activeMain == true) {
        $activeMain = '1';
    }
    return $activeMain;
}
```

Outside of my function I have:

```
$activeMain = (isset($_POST['activateBox'])) ? $_POST['activateBox'] : false;
activeCheck($activeMain);
//along with lots of other code that isn't relevant to my delima.
```

As it stands right now, my function doesn't do anything. I can get my code to work if I don't use a function (essentially take the if statement out and put it under isset in my main) but I want to use a function.

I'm throughly confused as to why my function returns no errors and has no effect on my code at all even though I've written plenty of functions before, this for some reason, no matter how simple it is, cuz I know it's simple, is proving to be so difficult for me.

What I want to happen is, my function to change the value of $activeMain to '1' if a checkbox has been selected on a HTML/PHP form I created.

Please help me out, and thank you.

Comment: You forgot to set it, you want `$activeMain = activeCheck($activeMain);`.

Comment: try `var_dump` too check ur variables along with your code. But maybe u should use `echo $activeMain;` instead of `return $activeMain;`

Comment: HAHHAHAHA Thank You @Dave Chen

Comment: You can also force a reference in your function, such as `function activeCheck(&$activeMain) {`, thus you don't need to return and it will work just only with `activeCheck($activeMain);`.